# How do I create an instance of another class, load an object with data and print it out?

Tags: java, constructor, instance, setter, getter

I am a complete noob (5th day programming) which explains why I have spent countless head-aching hours trying to solve this problem and still have not figured it out yet:

How do you create an instance of CarAndBikes, load it with information of 3 cars and print it out?

Here's my incomplete code to give you an idea of the problem:

```
    public class Vehicle {

        String manufacturer, model;
        int numberOfWheels;

        public Vehicle(String manufacturer, String model, int numberOfWheels) {

            this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
            this.model = model;
            this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels;
        }

        public String getManufacturer() {
            return manufacturer;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public int getNumberOfWheels() {
            return numberOfWheels;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + numberOfWheels +") '" + manufacturer + ", " + model + "'";
        }
    }

    public class CarAndBikes {

        private Vehicle[] items;
        private int nextFreeItem = 0;

        CarAndBikes (int size) {
            items = new Vehicle[size];

            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            items[i] = new Vehicle(manufacturer, model, numberOfWheels);
        }

        void addVehicle(String man, String mdl, int wheels) {
            items[nextFreeItem++].addVehicle(man, mdl, wheels);
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + items + ")";
        }
    }

public class TestProgram extends CarAndBikes{
    TestProgram(int size) {
        super(size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle1 = new Vehicle("Seat", "Ibiza", 4);
        Vehicle vehicle2 = new Vehicle("Reliant", "Robin", 3);
        Vehicle vehicle3 = new Vehicle("Honda", "Fireblade", 2);

        System.out.println(vehicle1);
        System.out.println(vehicle2);
        System.out.println(vehicle3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see any addVehicle() method in Vehicle class. Is your code even compiling?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to seperate cars and Bikes into seperate classes and then have a class to store a collection of them?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you'd be better off separating cars and bikes into separating cars and bikes into two seperate classes 'Car' and 'Bike' and then create a 3rd class to house a collection of those objects, that way you can use an List or ArrayList to store them and have a method to just print them out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

Public Class Garage
{
   private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles;

   Public Garage()
   {
     vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
   }

   public void addVehicle(Vehicle v)
   {
      vehicles.add(v);
   }

   public void getVehicles()
   {
     for(Vehicle v : vehicles)
     {
       System.out.Println(v.getModel());
     }
   }
}
```

You'll notice that the ArrayList accepts objects of type vehicle, well both cars and bikes extend vehicle so they will be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I notice the `toString()` method in `CarAndBikes` is using `toString()` on an array reference (and arrays don't override `toString()`). You could use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) like

```
public String toString() {
    // return "(" + items + ")";
    return Arrays.toString(items);
}
```

The [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) that you're getting is documented as,

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with it. Can you help me please? I've edited the code but there's still an error at  CarAndBikes (int size) {  AND   items[nextFreeItem++].addVehicle(man, mdl, wheels);